# Why scala List could take covariant type as paramenter in method +=

Tags: list, scala, covariant

Scala List is declared as

```
sealed abstract class List[+A] extends AbstractSeq[A] with LinearSeq[A] with     Product with GenericTraversableTemplate[A, List] with LinearSeqOptimized[A, List[A]] with java.io.Serializable
```

The method to prepend an element to a List is declared as

```
def +:(elem: A): List[A]
```

As type A is covariant, why the compiler does not complain since A appears in the contravariant position in +:?

Comment: could you reiterate your question, I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: I was wondering why the signature of method +: of class List does not break the rule of usage of covariant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because its full signature is:

```
def +:[B >: A, That](elem: B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That
```

The doc what you mentioned in the question is just the simplified one, you need to check the full signature of the method.